# What is a good synonym for a literally "small book"?

Tags: single-word-requests, books, publishing

I am writing the preface to a small book (4" x 6" with 200+ pages) where I have already used the term "small book". The opportunity to use the term again arose shortly thereafter and to avoid redundancy, I would like to inquire if anyone knows of a good synonym for "small book" that perhaps does not utilize the word *book?*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147692/discussion-on-question-by-i-chekhov-what-is-a-good-synonym-for-a-literally-sma); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Especially in the UK, a Pocket Book is a compact book (in terms of spatial dimensions) that may contain several hundred pages. It's quite common for these to be small yet length reference books. The USA usage of pocketbook to mean purse may be confusing to some readers, however.

Definition:
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pocketbook

Example:
https://www.foraging.co.uk/product/the-wild-food-uk-foraging-pocket-guide/

Comment: I bought a 'Pocket Book of Poetry' at Barnes & Noble in the Southern US; it's not a problem. I always said "pocketbook" to mean purse (some still do, esp. older people in rural areas), but it's less common now, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment we learn that it's a book of 999 quotations.

You could call it a **pocket-sized compendium**.